# Installing CartoDB on Raspberry Pi Model B?

Tags: carto, installation, raspberry-pi

Has anyone gotten CartoDB to work on a Raspberry Pi?

I was able to install everything (minus the PPAs and the two node apps) on my Pi that are in the README. I'm wondering if anyone else has done this or if they can help me with the remaining things. I doubt I'm missing anything with the PPAs, but the two node apps (which basically said things were not okay, couldn't find another app or something, don't recall) worry me.

As I noted in the comments, I'm installing from Github and using the README from there. I'm running on a Model B (512mb RAM). I want to have a development environment to play around with and figured my Pi would work alright (sure it might be a little slow, but that's okay). I'm also running raspbian built mid December 2013.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. The detail might matter here - please consider editing the question to add detail of which README you're following (version of CartoDB), what you're trying to install it on (Raspbian?) and the specific error messages.

Comment: Which Model? (A or B) and how much RAM do you have (256MB or 512MB).

Comment: You can run this on the Raspberry_Pi recommend a Class 10 SD Card https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/easy.html

Comment: Ah, very true, I forgot to mention those specifics :) I'm on a Model B (which has 512mb RAM). I'm running raspbian from NOOBs dated 2013-12-23 or there abouts. Looks like it was compiled on the 19 of Dec 2013, 3.10.24+ kernel.

Comment: I'm installing HEAD from github and following the README that's there.

Comment: Here's another update: I've manually compiled and installed libv8 (that took a very long time) with some patches I found online, need to find them again. Currently compiling node. Once libv8 and therubyracer were installed the ruby deps installed correctly.

Comment: It's an amazing project! How was it? You could share the results. :)

Comment: I'll try to install Cartodb on my Raspberry Pi 3 It replaced the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B it has: A 1.2GHz 64-bit quad-core ARMv8 CPU and 1GB of RAM Do you have updated which are the steps missing on readme of cartodb installation guide for Raspbian? I'll try to install on Raspbian Jessie :)

Comment: The Pi was too weak to really do much, I also had to compile lots myself. The Pi 2 should be much easier.

Comment: The Model B simply doesn't have enough horse power on its own to do this. The Pi 2 May, plus packages should be easier to find.

Comment: To keep this question open I think you should revise it to installing on the latest Raspberry Pi.  It sounds like you as the question asker concede that it was not viable on the configuration asked about in the question.

Comment: If I had a newer Pi I'd update the question, however I don't. I doubt there would be much issue on a newer Pi.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to relate to a hardware limitation.